# Does Bluetooth work during update process? Trackpad and keyboard unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

My keyboard and trackpad don’t work  but I’m able to use bluetooth mouse and keyboard. I’m worried about trying to update because if there’s some part of the process where I have to click next and it doesn’t use Bluetooth at that point im going to be screwed.

Comment: There's a lot of detail missing here. Imagine we cannot see over your shoulder what you're doing. You have to tell us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to know if Bluetooth works during update process. That’s it

Comment: Based on what we know so far, "It should, but it's always a good idea to have a wired alternative" might be the best answer you could get. Not sure whether this is good enough though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bluetooth works when you are updating your Mac. The only times it doesn’t is when the normal keyboard doesn’t work as well.

You likely just have Bluetooth issues or interference in this case. Any USB keyboard or mouse can be connected when you have challenges with Bluetooth - better to line them up now (and make sure your backup is current) if you suspect your Mac is not stable.

Answer (score -1):

It should work. Only when the specifically Bluetooth will update that time it should stop but after updating it should work fine.